# Visio AddIn (C#) for saving a page as *.svg

Tags: c#, svg, visio

I wrote a small C# Visio Addin which should export the current page of the Visio document as *.svg whenever the open Visio file is saved:

`Application.ActivePage.Export("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\example.svg");`

Unfortunately, when it runs this line it gets stuck in Visio with a window displaying "Preparing to save..." and a progress bar at 88%.

I tried several things (e.g. different target paths, running as administrator etc.) but nothing helped. It always gets stucked there and I can only click abort then.

When I do the same manually in Visio (Save as svg) then it works without any issue.

The same code with e.g. *.png instead of *.svg works well.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different file extension?

Comment: Does it do this for every input file, or just one? Can you look using ProcMon what's happening?

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, the same codee with e.g. *.png works well.

Comment: Have you tried saving as .svg with a simple page of just one rectangle?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe there is a progress dialog in the background, or some sort of question dialog? Try clicking ALT+TAB.

Comment: Okay, this is strange.. when I opened ProcMon (thanks for this tip @CodeCaster ) and without changing anything else (except a restart which I already did yesterday) it worked now. I have no idea why...

Comment: ...and when I close the ProcMon again, it does not longer work. Any idea why?

Comment: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1298602/why-do-programs-start-working-when-i-open-process-monitor)  mentions a similar situation.. however, there is no relevant answer.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn’t invest time/energy to solve this mysterious issue, I would go with jpg instead of svg or reset my windows machine, it’s save to assume your code will run on a different system, so resetting yours could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by running the above code in the event `Application.BeforeDocumentSave` instead of `Application.DocumentSaved` ...but no idea why it works now.